# Ironic question: Where to go for product recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There have been several questions that I thought of as '''It would be perfect to ask http://workplace.stackexchange.com where to get a good, basic 2"x3.5" color business cards now that Vistaprint makes smaller cards that look tacky on a MagnaCard backing''', except of course that this is an umbrella of forums where product recommendation questions are not deemed constructive.

So is there a recommended procedure for "I have a question that would be perfect for forum X except that it's a product recommendation question?" I know about other forums, and if I wanted a product recommendation for hardware to buy for Ubuntu or whatnot I would go to http://ubuntuforums.org and ask away.

But I'm not sure what to do with the above concern, which is classic workplace concern except for being a product recommendation request and nothing else. Do I just search for business and advertising forums to appropriately ask that question?

Thanks,

Comment: Or I suppose you could just go search for "business cards" on Google. It'll give you a list of sites that will make them for you, which is basically what you'd get by asking for recommendations on a forum.

Comment: Answer from an SE expert that just poped up: "Me: Hey, what about business cards, standard 2"x3.5". Where can I get those?" "**Expert:** I don't know.". I guess that's the best you'll get from SE on this type of issue, sorry. (:

Comment: Am I just dense, because I don't detect any irony?

Comment: One comment about searching for "business cards:" the motivation for the question mentioned is that Vistaprint cut corners a bit and shrunk its business cards, imperceptibly for most purposes, but in a way that creates problems with a MagnaCard backing, which is standard business card size. The best way I see going off of a search is to ask the first SERP results whether they serve exactly 2"x3.5" cards, or good-enough-for-government-work-sized business cards. That's a little bit of an expertise request, but it's not immediately visible from the homepages. Vistaprint certainly gave no warning.

Comment: Is it that _all current Stackexchange sites disallow product recommendations by policy_ or _the stackexchange system built in such a way that it makes it poorly suited to product recommendations_? If it’s the former, might `product-recommendations.stackexchange.com` be possible? Basically I want a crowdsourced Wirecutter.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange is not the place to ask for product recommendations as these are opinion based instead of fact based, that's why those types of questions are closed for not being constructive.

[This blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) on the Stack Exchange Blog explains this into further detail.